# UndoRedo.Manager and JCheckBox

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, document, undo-redo

I am using the UndoRedo.Manager to implement Undo/Redo functionality in a Netbeans RCP application. The undoableEditListener can be added to any Document, that limits its use to text-related fields. Does anyone know how i can add such a listener to elements without a Document, like a JCheckBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create custom CompoundEdits or even separate edits. See for example the edits merging in one http://java-sl.com/tip_merge_undo_edits.html

I think all you need is to keep own events stack and implement custom UndoableEdits which don't change model (Document) but change state. In other words you need more complicated model to keep checkbox state as well as Document in one. All the complicated model changes (state change or docuemnt change) should be represented by custom UndoableEdit class. The class instance could be wrapper for Docuemnt edit event or just custom event.

Comment: I was hoping for an out-of-the-box solution, but it seems I´ll have to do it your way. Atleast, it isn´t really complicated. Thanks.